# Rsnapshot frequently exits with error 12 when processing tar.gz file

Tags: backup, postgresql, rsync, rsnapshot

I have an rsnapshot tool to backup some machines. It's running on a QNAP NAS and backing up several machines.

One of the things I backup is database backups. On one machine I create both plain text backup files, and a tar.gz of said files. Plain text ~4GB, tar.gz ~1GB.

A while ago I decided to rsnapshot only the tar.gz (no need to backup both files). The problem is that 19 out of 20 times the backup script fails with

```
ERROR: /opt/bin/rsync returned 12.
```

Upon investigation I see this happens when procesing the tar.gz file.
I don't think the problem happens with the plain text file (even though it is 4GB).

Do you know what could be happening?

**Edit:**
Here's some of the logs I get when running rsync manually. This first one seems to be error 30, which I also get sometimes:

> srv/backup/database/daily/mydb.bak
>      51458092 100%    3.96MB/s    0:00:12 (xfer#2, to-check=1007/1036)
>
> [receiver] io timeout after 90 seconds -- exiting rsync error: timeout
>   in data send/receive (code 30) at io.c(140) [receiver=3.0.8] rsync:
>   connection unexpectedly closed (40 bytes received so far) [generator]
>
> rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at
>   io.c(601) [generator=3.0.8]

Comment: Could you run rsync manually with the -v flag and post the error message?

Comment: Added a first log that returned error 30.